# Replace single quotes in Java

Tags: java, escaping

I have developed a java app for read given xml files and make `SQL INSERT or UPDATE statements` with data in xml files. amuse there are some statements as below.

```
INSERT INTO BUYERS(BUYER_ID, BUYER_NAME) VALUES ('100', 'A's Shop') 
INSERT INTO BUYERS(BUYER_ID, BUYER_NAME) VALUES ('101', 'ABC's Shop') 
INSERT INTO BUYERS(BUYER_ID, BUYER_NAME) VALUES ('102', 'ZXCVBN's Shop') 
INSERT INTO BUYERS(BUYER_ID, BUYER_NAME) VALUES ('103', 'RR's Shop') 

UPDATE BUYERS SET BUYER_NAME = 'MKO's Shop' WHERE BUYER_ID = 151
UPDATE BUYERS SET BUYER_NAME = 'DDD's Shop' WHERE BUYER_ID = 160
```

when i'm try to execute those statements, i got an error as `ORA-00917: missing comma` because there is a `single quote` in value of `BUYER_NAME`.

i have tried to replace this `single quote` using `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` method in java. but it replace all `single quotes` in my query.

i need to replace only the `single quote` with `BUYER_NAME`. How could i do that?

Comment: When you fetch the `BUYER_NAME` data from the XML files, escape the quotes before constructing the statements

Comment: Stop it altogether and use PreparedStatement. This is a compete waste of your time.

Answer (score 2):

try it using preparedStatement().

Answer (score 1):

Like Jon Lin commented, the best way is probably to change your construction method so that it escapes all "dangerous" characters from the XML text when creating the inserts.

That way you can control exactly what ends up in the Insert statements.

Please keep in mind, if the XML is not built by you, that simply concatenating Strings to build Insert/Update statements can be extremely dangerous due to the possibility of SQL Injections.

Almost always, inserting and updating data through PreparedStatemens is the best way of doing something like this, but it's hard to tell what your requirements are from the question.

Comment: No. The best way is to use PreparedStatement.

Comment: Did you miss the part where I say PreparedStatements are probably the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

since you are parsing the xml and making the query string 
just make sure you Replace single quotes before making the query Statements

Answer (score 0):

Try it using  to replace this single quote

```
String str = 'A's Shop'

str=replace(str," ' "," '' ") // Here it will store as "A''s Shop"

Or preparedStatement().
```

Answer (score 0):

A secure (and easy) way is to build your StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("UPDATE BUYERS SET BUYER_NAME = '";
sb.append("MKO''s Shop" ) // or the (String) parameter build otherwhere
sb.append("' WHERE BUYER_ID = ");
sb.append(100); // Integer are transormed in String here
```

and use `sb.toString();`

*Edit :* replaced with double `''` inside String

You can do  the same things with

```
INSERT INTO BUYERS(BUYER_ID, BUYER_NAME) VALUES ('
100
', '
name''s 
')
```